# In Chromium, where are the UI composed?

Tags: java, android, c++, chromium

I'm trying to add a UI functionality on Chromium (not via extensions), specifically on Android.

I've been digging through Chromium's source and it seems every file I've checked are not really related to what I want to do.

To be fair, I don't know C++, but I feel like I should still be able to perceive if I see the right code.

I'm trying to look for where the actual UI code is written like if it was HTML it'll be something like:

```
<Main>
  <Tabs />
  <AddressBar />
  <BookmarksBar />
  <Content />
</Main>
```

I'm not expecting it to be XML/HTML. In Android, you could also do it programmatically e.g

```
// Not exactly. Just a demonstration.
Layout layout = new Layout()
Text text = new Text()
layout.add(text)
```

Where is the composition of these elements go?

I've checked stuff in (and some of the subdirectories in it):

- chrome/
- chrome/browser/
- ui/
- ui/views/

But I didn't saw what I want.

For example, I also wanted to see where the Home page might be and I've checked the following without luck:

- https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/110.0.5440.1/chrome/browser/ui/webui/app_home/app_home_ui.cc
- https://github.com/chromium/chromium/tree/110.0.5440.1/chrome/browser/new_tab_page

So where can I find:

- where the UI elements are composed together?
- the UI components definition?

Comment: *I feel like I should still be able to perceive if I see the right code.* I give you about 60-40 in your favour. C++ can get <expletive deleted>ing weird. You should be able to up your odds by finding out what UI framework Chromium uses, [Aura](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/aura/) in most cases last time I stumbled into Chrome (but that was literally years ago), and looking for that framework's signature.

Comment: The Chromium UI is a WebView. It does not use the native UI components.

Comment: I'm a bit confused with your comments. Are your comments mutually exclusive or the same?

Comment: Just making sure you've seen: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/docs/ui/android/overview.md and https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/ui/android/BUILD.gn